# Trouble with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have uploaded a question about this but it hasn't been solved so I am re-posting it.

I am experiencing a problem in installing `Postgresql` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.
What I did was:

1. `sudo su -`
2. `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`
3. `update-rc.d postgresql enable`
4. `service postgresql start`

Doing #3, I got:

```
    update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match postgresql Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
    update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match postgresql Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
    Enabling system startup links for /etc/init.d/postgresql ...
    Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/postgresql ...
    /etc/rc0.d/K21postgresql
    /etc/rc1.d/K21postgresql
    /etc/rc2.d/S19postgresql
    /etc/rc3.d/S19postgresql
    /etc/rc4.d/S19postgresql
    /etc/rc5.d/S19postgresql
    /etc/rc6.d/K21postgresql
    Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/postgresql ...
    /etc/rc0.d/K21postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql
    /etc/rc1.d/K21postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql
    /etc/rc6.d/K21postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql
    /etc/rc2.d/S19postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql
    /etc/rc3.d/S19postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql
    /etc/rc4.d/S19postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql
    /etc/rc5.d/S19postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql
```

In doing #4, I am getting this error:

```
    The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
    2015-07-17 21:54:24 PHT LOG:  could not open secondary authentication file "@admins" as "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/admins": No such file or directory
    2015-07-17 21:54:24 PHT LOG:  could not open secondary authentication file "@admins" as "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/admins": No such file or directory
    2015-07-17 21:54:24 PHT LOG:  could not open secondary authentication file "@demodbs" as "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/demodbs": No such file or directory
    2015-07-17 21:54:24 PHT LOG:  end-of-line before authentication method
    2015-07-17 21:54:24 PHT CONTEXT:  line 75 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf"
    2015-07-17 21:54:24 PHT FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

I thought I installed `Postgresql` correctly. What is wrong?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html It seems like the provided pg_hba.conf attempts to include non-existing files. For a start: comment out all lines in `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` with @admins, etc in them.

Comment: I also use Ubuntu 14.04 with postgre 9.3 and I don't have this files. Do you have an old and invalid pg_hba.conf? Moreover, postgresql is automatically added to startup. Offtopic: And why do you sudo su - and then execute another sudo command?

Comment: @Bevor I was just following a guide on the net about installing Postgresql. His method was like that :O

Comment: @joop my `pg_hba.conf` file is "empty" as in when I open it with sublime text, there is nothing.

Comment: `CONTEXT:  line 75 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf"` suggests that is has at least 75 lines. Do you have the correct location? is/was it a symlink?

Comment: @joop I have opened the file using: `subl /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` and there is nothing shown.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by following joop's advice in the comment.

I have opened the `pg_hba.conf` using `sudo` (without sudo, it appears to be empty) then I commented out all lines that have `@admins`.

Comment: The file appearing empty is a *feature* of your editor. A normal editor would warn you with "access denied" or "invalid path" or or "new file".